# Do I need to mail my original US green card along with the UK standard visitor visa application to UKVI?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I submitted my UK standard visitor visa application, and required to submit the following:

1. Original passport
2. Evidence of funds
3. Evidence of US residency

I've scanned and submitted all three online. Do I still need to ship evidence of funds and the original US green card along with my passport to UKVI in New York?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the answer to this question on this [VFS page](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/gbr/supporting-documents) under "Non-settlement applications". It says:

> Please only include photocopies of your Green Card – do not send in originals.